# (Android) List in dialog with only one item with a checkbox

Tags: android, list, checkbox, dialog, alert

Ok, I've searched for this for a while now, but I can't find anything.  My app displays a students school schedule in a list and when the user clicks a class in the list it displays a dialog that lists a few options (Edit, Delete, Set Alarm).  Edit and Delete are easy, because they are clicked and something happens, but I need help with the "Set Alarm" option. I don't want it to be clickable, I just want a checkbox to the right of it that will toggle an alarm on or off.  Here's the code for my dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(courseName)
    .setItems(R.array.courseList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch(which) {
            case LIST_EDIT:
                break;
            case LIST_DELETE:
                break;
            case LIST_ALARM:
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Right now I have the list options in a string array in my resources xml file with the id courseList.  LIST_EDIT, LIST_DELETE, and LIST_ALARM are final int's corresponding to their index in the list.  I'm really not sure how to add a checkbox to the alarm list item, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with **fragment** you can use a **FragmentDialog** and then in the method **onCreateDialog** you create the dialog as you want.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
_list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
_adapter = new AdapterDialog(_context);
_list.setAdapter(_adapter);
//
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
builder.setView(view);  builder.setTitle("Dialog").setPositiveButton(getActivity().getString(android.R.string.ok), this);

return builder.create();
```

Or something like that
And then create the dialog with a singleton method or a constructor

```
_dialog = Dialog.newInstance(R.string.title, this);
_dialog.setCancelable(true);
_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

With your aproach you can't add something more than the "buttons" if you want to have a custom row in your list you must use an adapter

hope it helps

Comment: For anyone still following this, it does indeed work.  Thanks!